# webapi post method with parameters doesn't work

Tags: c#, ajax, post, asp.net-web-api

When I call my webAPI controller that contains a post method with NO parameters it goes to the method.  However, when I pass parameters (and when I update the api controller with paramters as well) into this see the snippet below the 1st snippet I get the 405 error that it doesn't support POST.

```
var captchURL = "/api/Captcha";  
$.ajax({
       url: captchURL,
       dataType: 'json',
       contentType: 'application/json',
       type: 'POST'
})



var jsondata = {solution: "7", answer: "7"};
    var captchURL = "/api/Captcha";  
    $.ajax({
           url: captchURL,
           dataType: 'json',
           contentType: 'application/json',
           type: 'POST',
           data: JSON.stringify(jsondata)
    })
```

**UPDATE - Controller Code:**

```
public class CaptchaController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ICaptchaService _service;
    public CaptchaController(ICaptchaService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public Captcha Get()
    {
        return _service.Get();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public bool Post(string solution, string answer)
    {
        return _service.Post();

    }
}
```

**UPDATE - WebApiConfig:**

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Is it because I don't have the solution and answer params (in my WebApiConfig) that it doesn't recognize them?

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Post code from your controller

Comment: @jpgrassi - I updated with the controller code - I also just added the parameters to the Post method

Comment: @webdad3 why did you stringify the data i think you should not `data: jsondata` is enough

Comment: @meda - tried it both ways and got the same error.

Comment: Did you check the console to see if there were any errors logged?

Comment: @webdad3 - Have you checked that the controller receives what you expect? Add a watch on "this.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result", and inspect the payload. For Mauros and Bimals answers to work, it should be a json-string: "{"solution": "foo", "answer":"bar"}". You must temporarily remove the [FromBody] parameter from the Action, otherwise it seems like WebApi clears the request content.

Comment: if the problem is in WebApiConfig it would return 404 instead of 405.is the problem occur in and IIS environment or Development  environment ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a slightly different method of setting the route, but I prefer it.
In your controller code add a route prefix and routes for each method that will represent a POST of GET request...

```
[RoutPrefix("Captcha")]
public class CaptchaController : ApiController
{

    [Route("Post/{solution}/{answer}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public bool Post(string solution, string answer)
    {
        return _service.Post();

    }
}
```

This should work as long as you are setting the path correctly, using the correctly typed parameters, and returning a correctly typed value. If you use a Model then you do not have to add the parameters into the Route path.

This worked for me when I was setting up my WebAPI. If anyone sees anything wrong with explanation please let me know. I am still learning (and always will be), but just wanted to let you know what I did that worked.

Answer (score 6):

create a model

```
public class Captcha {
    public string solution { get; set; }
    public string answer { get; set; }
}
```

the controller is this

```
[HttpPost]
public string Post([FromBody] Captcha cap)
{
    return cap.solution + " - " + cap.answer;
}
```

Comment: When I did this I got into the controller but "cap" was null.

Comment: are you sure your uri is correct? try to do this var captchURL = "api/captcha";

Comment: positive.  I changed the captchURL as well with no change.

Comment: try to remove private readonly ICaptchaService _service;
    public CaptchaController(ICaptchaService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

Comment: you can also use the new c# record object (good use case of records) instead.
--    public record(string Solution, string Answer)

Answer (score 3):

Add another **MapHttpRoute** which will accept '**solution**' and '**answer**' as parameters

sample :

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{solution}/{answer}",
            defaults: new { solution = RouteParameter.Optional, answer= RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[HttpPost]

public bool Post(Captcha cap)
{
    return _service.Post();
}
```

And

Change `data: JSON.stringify(jsondata)` to `data : jsondata` .

Answer (score 1):

The Reason it doesn't work is because there is not route that will accept 2 parameter at your [post] address - api/captcha/.

you have 2 options, either set up attribute routing in controller as

```
[Route("Post/{solution}/{answer}")]
[HttpPost]
public bool Post(string solution, string answer)
{
  return _service.Post();

}
```

or create a model as

```
Public class CaptchaModel
{
   Public string Solution {get; set;}
   Public string Answer {get; set;}
}
```

And in your action method

```
[HttpPost]
public bool Post([FromBody] CaptchaModel model)
{
  var solution = model.solution;
  var answer = model.answer;
  .........
  return _service.Post();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to www.asp.net,

"when an HTTP method is configured for use on the server, but it has been disabled for a given URI, the server will respond with an HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed error."

Further reference on 405

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications

Answer (score 1):

You must remove JSON.stringify(data) from your request and then add [FromBody] in front your model. Then it will work.